# Access cookies from another service

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, hexagonal-architecture

I'm trying to work with a clean and hexagonal architecture for my sveltekit frontend, connecting to an external API.
When I want to load some data for a page, inside my `load` function I instantiate a simple command/DTO that I pass to a usecase class, which passes it on to a handler class, which then calls the external API to get the data via a gateway class.
Now architecture wise, the load function is inside the Infrastructure layer, then command/usecase/handler are all inside the Application layer, then the gateway is in the Infrastructure layer but I instantiate it inside my handler via dependency injection on a Domain interface so I'm good on that.

Problem is, I need access to the cookies in my gateway, so I can attach them to my outgoing request and authenticate on my external API. But those cookies are only accessible inside my `load` function as far as I know, and I don't want to drill either the whole original request or the cookies through my whole usecase because the Application layer shouldn't care about that.

I would like to get access to existing cookies for the current original request inside my gateway directly, is there any way I could do that in SvelteKit while still being careful about not sharing data between users on the node server?

Comment: I imagine that if you are using dependency injection, then the correct way to do it is by injecting something giving you access to the cookies where you need them, and how you accomplish this depends very much on which dependency injection library you are using. Which is it?

Comment: I'm using typed-inject. There is the possibility of choosing the scope of each injected class, between singleton and transient. I could have a RequestContextProvider where I store cookies from my hooks.server and then inject it inside my gateway class, but how could I do that in a way that is safe for not sharing data between users? If I make its instantiation transient I won't be able to have the same instance in my hooks.server as well as later down the line in my gateway, am I?

Comment: I'm no DI expert, but it seems like you in your server hooks just want to resolve your dependencies only once? With your variable cookie information, I don't think that's possible; I think you should use transient and resolve your dependencies inside the `load()` function each time it's called. Otherwise you'll end up with risky code if all HTTP requests you receive will share the same dependency instances.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you for giving me a nudge in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a new DI injector in each `load` function instead of one for the application. That way I can pass the request to the injector factory and have it injected directly into the gateway class (or into a `RequestContextProvider` class that is then injected into the gateway, whatever works best for your case).